# how to update form in PrimeFaces layoutUnit

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I would like to use primeface `<p:layout>` to create two `<p:layoutUnit>`s. west `<p:layoutUnit>` for menu and the center `<p:layoutUnit>` for rending pages when clicking the items on menu.
As the `<p:menu>` must be wrapped in `<h:form>`, so as my contents in center as I need to use tables to display data. So my xhtml page looks like following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <f:facet name="first">
                <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
                <title>PrimeFaces</title>
            </f:facet>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <p:layout fullPage="true">
                <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="175" header="Left" collapsible="true">
                    <p:menu>
                        <p:submenu label="testUpdate">
                            <p:menuitem value="open" id="open" actionListener="#{backingBean.open()}" update=":center_form"/>
                            <p:menuitem value="close" id="close" actionListener="#{backingBean.close()}" update=":center_form"/>
                        </p:submenu>
                    </p:menu>
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                    <p:panel id="center_panel" rendered="#{backingBean.render}"> 
                        <h:form id="center_form">
                            testing
                        </h:form>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:layoutUnit>
            </p:layout>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

and my web.xml:

```xml
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
            <param-value>Development</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

Question is the ajax seems not working properly when I click the "open" and "close", I have to fresh my connects by reload the page manually to let the page update.

May I know whether it is possible to be done?
if so, is anything wrong inside my code?
or what could I do to let the center layoutUnit could update automatically when I click the item on the menu?

Comment: you should use `h:head` to include jsf libs for ajax.

Comment: tell me if it works or not!

Comment: This is not the problem as I just give my part of code... Otherwise the page couldn't be up normally but not just an update problem.. Sorry about this.. I will paste my full code later

Comment: your web.xml is needed too

Comment: Thanks, i am outside now, I will update my code and web.xml tonight

Answer (score 0):

add this to your web.xml:

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class> 
</listener>
```

try `update="@all"`

Comment: It's not working. I even can't build after I add the listener. firstly I am using Primefaces but not myfaces. Secondly please check this: (http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6956), @all is not supported by Primefaces